# swaping multiple images of mouse over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover

When I hover image consecutively changes three different images. But the problem is: it shows only two images. Third image missing. How can I solve this problem?

```
function changeimage(img_id)
{
    var prefix = "http://247nywebdesign.com/";
    prefix += "Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_";
    $("#" + img_id).fadeOut(1500);
    $("#" + img_id).attr("src", prefix + "03.jpg").fadeIn(500);
    $("#" + img_id).attr("src", prefix + "03.jpg").show(4000);
    $("#" + img_id).attr("src", prefix + "05.jpg").fadeIn(500);
    $("#" + img_id).attr("src", prefix + "05.jpg").fadeIn(2000);
    $("#" + img_id).attr("src", prefix + "05.jpg").show(4000);
    $("#" + img_id).attr("src", prefix + "05.jpg").fadeOut(1500);
    $("#" + img_id).attr("src", prefix + "03.jpg").fadeIn(1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L7Pcx/4/

Comment: "fade in" + "show" number 3, "fade in" + "fade in" + "show" + "fade out" number 5, "fade in" number 3... Seriously, what are you trying to achieve?? Blinking images in a chaotic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this and mark if you feel this is the same being expected.

The images above are for reference only. Use the last image for hover test.

http://jsbin.com/towib/

Answer (score 0):

You need to queue all the operations

```
$("#"+img_id)
  .fadeOut(1500)
  .queue(function(next) { $(this).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg"); next(); })   
  .fadeIn(500)
  // ...
```

Comment: can you show in js fiddle

Answer (score -1):

Pass it by end of first fadein effect like;

```
    $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg").fadeIn(500, 
    function () {
          $("#"+img_id).attr("src","http://247nywebdesign.com/Testing/nurses-jewel/php/pdt_images/prdt_03.jpg").show(4000);
    }
});
```

Regards

Comment: can you show in js fiddle